# How to convert multiple telethon session files(.session) into single tdata folder with python?

Tags: python, telegram

I have multiple sessions files (.session) for telethon. I need to gather 2 or 3 of them and convert into single tdata folder. This means that i want to create tdata folder,with which opened desktop client will have 2 or 3 accounts at once.

I tried use opentele library, but it can only convert one session file into tdata with one account and doesn't allow multiple accounts at once.